# Unable to create or edit new Post (Node & Mongo)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I already solved the problem but now IT is back. I want to save new artist to the website or edit them but now its like the application doesnt connect to the DB but it is! I checked.

```
const
    express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    Post = require('../models/post');


// Define which ImageTypes are avaiable to upload
const imageMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg'];


// All admin Routes
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    renderNewPage(res, new Post())
})
// New Route
router.get('/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin/createPost/index', {
        layout: 'layouts/admin',
        // Defined in models/post, gets variables
        post: new Post()
    });
})
// New Post create
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        // get information from sended new Post (above) and defines variables to use in ejs files
        surname: req.body.surname,
        name: req.body.name,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        birthday: req.body.birthday,
        technic: req.body.technic,
        techPricerangeFrom: req.body.techPricerangeFrom,
        techPricerangeTo: req.body.techPricerangeTo
    })
    // set FilePond saving files to DB
    saveProfilpic(post, req.body.profilpic)

    try {   // await for new post to safe
        const newPost = await post.save();
        res.redirect('admin');
    } catch {
        renderNewPage(res, post, true)
    }
})


//? Singe Artist Show, Edit, Upate, Delete
// Create single artists page 
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Show Artist' + req.params.id)
})

// Edit artist
router.get('/:id/edit', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const findPost = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
        res.render('admin/edit', {
            layout: 'layouts/admin',
            post: findPost
        })
    } catch {
        res.redirect('/admin')
    }
})

// Update artist text
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let post;
    try {
        post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
        post.surname = req.body.surname,
        post.name = req.body.name,
        post.bio = req.body.bio,
        post.birthday = req.body.birthday,
        post.technic = req.body.technic,
        post.techPricerangeFrom = req.body.techPricerangeFrom,
        post.techPricerangeTo = req.body.techPricerangeTo,
        post.profilpic = req.body.profilpic

        await post.save();
        res.redirect(`/admin`);
    } catch {
        if (post == null) {
            res.redirect('/admin')
        }
        else {
            res.render('admin/edit', {
                layout: 'layouts/admin',
                post: post,
            })
        }
    }
})

// Define functions

async function renderNewPage(res, post, hasError = false) {
    // Implement all Posts (artists) in the DB
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({}).collation({ locale: 'en', strength: 2 }).sort({ name: 1 })  // wait and find all post and sort my name
        const params = {
            layout: 'layouts/admin',
            posts: posts,    // take all posts from await Post.find({}) and overrides the updates the posts
        }
        if (hasError) params.errorMessage = 'Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten'
        res.render('admin/index', params);
    } catch (err) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}

// func for dave files via filepond
function saveProfilpic(post, profilpictureEncoded) {
    if (profilpictureEncoded == null) return
    const profpic = JSON.parse(profilpictureEncoded);
    if (profpic != null && imageMimeTypes.includes(profpic.type)) { // If the file is a json obj & from the type image (jpg, png)
        post.profilpic = new Buffer.from(profpic.data, 'base64')    // Buffer.from(where, how)
        post.profilpicType = profpic.type
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

all types in the model/post file are Strings.If I want to change something it redirects me to /admin, what means its a error. I got all latest packages (express, mongoose, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I found your answer as I was working on the same tutorial, so I'm still quite new to this, but in my case the problem was related to having a missing '=' in the index page view.
Do you have the '=' character within the <% %> part so that the id is actually included in the link? If not, the link won't include the actual id, since the '=' is needed to not just access a variable but also display it.

```
<% artists.forEach(Artist=> { %>
    <div><%= Artist.last_name %></div>
    <a href="/artists/<%= Artist.id %>">View</a>
<% }) %>
```

Hope this helps, and feel free to correct me, as I'm also just starting to learn the basics.